# Android: network requests from a background service started separately from the app

Tags: android, networking, service

I'm facing a problem trying to fetch data by the background service started at the device boot time. When run from the dedicated application, it retrieves the data just fine, but when run separately, it starts correctly but returns nothing. It doesn't rely on any other classes, it uses only its own methods.

Is it possible at all to execute http requests from a background service started in that way?

BackgroundService.java fragment:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {  
    new BackgroundTask(this).run();
}
```

The BackgroundTask class does all his job in its run() method containing the code for http requests which works fine if the service is run from the application. Do I have to do something about onBind method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `startService()` from you `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast receiver. Your Service will be considered active until it calls [`stopSelfResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelfResult%28int%29) or [`stopSelf()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28int%29), or somebody calls [`stopService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) on your service. And while service is active it can run any web-request it needs (this should be done in separate thread of course).

You should refer to ["Creating a Started Service"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#CreatingAService) section in Android Documentation for more details.